# Kinect SDK 1.7 InteractionFrame

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, xbox

I want to know based on kinect for windows SDK 1.7, which have grab function under the InteractionFrame.

Is it possible to only use one hand only eg: right hand only grab?

I had try to make it only 1 hand detect (right hand), but it seems that there is some sort of ghost mouse when i move my left hand.

this is what i had tried:
playerInfo.HandPointers[1].HandEventType == InteractionHandEventType.Grip

but stil there is another pointer merely visible.

thank you very much.

Comment: Are you implementing `INuiInteractionClient` interface ? Especially it's `GetInteractionInfoAtLocation` member ?

Answer (score 0):

Tlga, I am having major problems setting up the interaction events in my program. Is there anyway you could help me since it seems as though you already have these in place.

I am about to pull my hair out

Ben

Chefbennyj at gmail dot com